# How to store input type checkbox into json object using either Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, checkbox

I wanted to store all my clicked input accordions(<`input type="checkbox">`) into json object, I have tried it but it is storing/taking the last input accordion clicked event only, it is not storing/taking all the input clicked accordions that is whatever I click on any accordion(of `<input type="checkbox">`) that should store into json object using either Javascript or jQuery ?

I am not sure where I am doing wrong ? Please help me regarding this ? Thanks in advance. [Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/E4acF/1648/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing `submitButtonValue[name] = $(this).val();` and the name you are getting it from `$(this).attr('name');` on click of `checkbox` which is same for all the `checkboxes`. So everytime it replaces the value since `object` will have only one name contained. I would suggest you to either use different names for each `checkbox` or find some other way to uniquely store your `checkbox` values.

**[A Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/E4acF/1650/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: I have one query here, how can I provide an alert message(Like: Please click accordions first before hitting Submit button) if I click directly Submit button instead of clicking my checkbox types or accordions ?

Comment: @Dhana.. Added a code in your submit `click event` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/E4acF/1651/)** check and revert if you have any doubts on that..

Comment: If I hit directly Submit button, alert message is coming fine, but even after clicking checkbox types and then Submit also, alert message is showing up(this time it shoudn't come and only json object should show ?)

Comment: @Dhana Sorry but I could not replicate what you said.. Check the `DEMO`  in last comment once again and test it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101968/discussion-between-dhana-and-guruprasad-rao).