# How to show alert message if I hit Submit button directly and need to show json object after clicking for input types and then Submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, checkbox

I wanted to show one alert message if I click directly Submit button instead of clicking my `<input type="checkbox">` directly only. I have tried it at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/E4acF/1652/), but it is getting alert message every time (that is if I directly click Submit button - showing alert message and after clicking of any `<input type-"checkbox">` and then hitting Submit button - also showing alert message, this time I need to show only json object on console, not alert message).

Comment: you can paste your code here too

Comment: @YoYo, created Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/E4acF/1652/ .

Comment: i think its working the way you want

Comment: What is exactly your problem? because apparently it works as you expect

Comment: @YoYo, no, it's now working as per my requirement, it is working for: If I directly hit Submit-showing message, but if I click <input type="checkbox"> and Submit: then this time also it is showing alert message and not showing json object ?(so, I don't need alert message for this second case, need only json object)

Comment: Did't you ask the same question earlier in the morning ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076940/how-to-store-input-type-checkbox-into-json-object-using-either-javascript-or-jqu

Comment: @Dhana do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/E4acF/1655/

Comment: @RayonDabre, yeah, I have asked the same question, but I am not able to get json object for the second case and showing alert message(i need json object and don't need alert message for the second case that is I if I click <input type="checkbox" and then Submit)

Comment: @elio.d, I need like: no, it's now working as per my requirement, it is working for: If I directly hit Submit-showing message, but if I click <input type="checkbox"> and Submit: then this time also it is showing alert message and not showing json object ?(so, I don't need alert message for this second case, need only json object)

Comment: please you go through your jsfiddle ,,,its working as per your need ,,,have a look... you are completely unclear

Comment: @歐津柏, look like mine and your's are same, I need: it is working for: If I directly hit Submit-showing message, but if I click <input type="checkbox"> and Submit: then this time also it is showing alert message and not showing json object ?(so, I don't need alert message for this second case, need only json object)

Comment: @YoYo, my requirement is different from my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/E4acF/1652/, as it is giving alert message when I hit Submit button directly(it is fine), But if I click my any <input type="checkbox" and then if I hit Submit button-it is showing the alert message(I don't need this alert this time) and it is not giving my json object ? Kindly check once,

Comment: @Dhana by <input type="checkbox"> I suppose you mean when you click on one of the 4 panels[Title one, Title two, Title three, Title four] and then you click Submit you want it also to show the message 'Please select a checkbox and hit Submit! to show json object' using alert, am i right?

Comment: @歐津柏, No, at that time I don't want to show alert message, I need to show only json object(when I click on one of the 4 panels and then clicking on submit)

Comment: @Dhana And where would you want to show it? you do know it is giving you the json you want, right?

Comment: @歐津柏, I want to show json object on my console, this should happen only when I clicking on any of the 4 panels and then clicking of Submit button only(No alert is required), as I am not seeing any json object now.

Comment: @Dhana you are not seeing any object because you JSON.stringify your object, that's why you see only string in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101972/discussion-between-dhana-and-).

Comment: Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/E4acF/1662/ . Thanks all !!